# Aligning CSS icon with text

Tags: html, css

I've created a close button in CSS that I'm struggling to align with regular text. Its containing span element appears to align with the adjacent text, but not the children divs.

```
<a class="event-filter button" href="#">Filter name
  <span class="close-button">
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
  </span>
</a>

.close-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.close-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-button .menu-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.close-button .menu-bar-top {
  border-bottom: none;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 8px);
}
.close-button .menu-bar-bottom {
  border-top: none;
  top: 22px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -7px);
}
```

http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/vgXxQG

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: block` and align the close button with `vertical-align: middle` on the `.close-button` class. [Here is a demonstration](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNGZBw).

Setting `display: block` will cause the close icon to wrap. `inline-block` behaves as an inlined element, but allows you to set the width and height.

With that fixed, the icon is on the same line but it's not aligned. `vertical-align: middle` center-aligns (vertically) the button with the text.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're demonstrating. The `.close-button` class now has `inline-block` twice (was already added) and in your Pen, the button is bigger. I added `vertical-align: middle`, but when the button's at 1x1em, it's still not aligned. Thanks

Comment: You're right, I missed the second `inline-block`. Answer updated. Can you demonstrate what you mean when you say the button is not aligned at 1em? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: I made a mistake and left two sets of `display` and `width`/`height` properties on `.close-button`. This Pen is accurate: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/vgXxQG.

Comment: Good to know you've fixed it. Consider self-answering your question so it might help others in the future!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to say that I removed the extra properties, but the button is still not aligned in my last Pen as originally described.

Comment: Looks like your CSS transform is breaking the alignment. You could add a `margin-top` to the span, but at this point I'd consider using an SVG or other icon image instead

Answer (score 0):

When justifying text vertically, line-height is your freind:

```
a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: grey;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.close-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  z-index: 15;
  top: -2px; /* tweeked your placement a little */
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;

  &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Setting the anchor's line height to the height of your close box will center the text, vertically, in that space.